# Forwarding <my ip>:<port> to localhost:80/dir/ (apache)

Tags: apache-http-server, port, forwarding

Hello again StackExchange! First post on Superuser.

I've installed apache and PHP on my computer and it works just fine when i enter "localhost" on my computer. But what i want, is when someone types `http://<my ip>:<random port number that isn't used>` i want it to redirect to `http://localhost/internet/`. How do i do this with port forwarding? And what do i need to configure in Apache?

I know this might be question #87465094 on port forwarding, but i haven't seen any solutions for my problem here on Superuser nor the rest of the internet.

Thew

Comment: A `Redirect` directive in your Apache configuration for that host should be sufficient: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html

Comment: @OliverSalzburg So for example, is the code i need `Redirect /internetdocs http://my-ip:port/`? And where do i need to put the code? In the `.htaccess` of my `www` folder? Or what? (I'm new to management as you can see.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you're mixing two concepts into one idea.

- TCP/IP Port Forwarding
- HTTP Redirection

You can achieve what you want by combining the two, but they are separate concepts.

### HTTP Redirection

So, let's ignore port forwarding for the time being. Let's set up the redirection part first.

```
$ sudo editor /etc/apache2/sites-available/thews_site
```

This creates a new configuration file for a new *site* configuration in Apache. In it, we can place the whole configuration for our site.

#### Our VirtualHost

Let's define your new Apache site:

```
NameVirtualHost *:12345
<VirtualHost *:12345>
        Redirect / http://www.superuser.com
</VirtualHost>
```

This creates a new site that can be reached on any local IP, but **only** on port `12345`.

The site definition itself is rather short. It only has 1 configuration entry. The redirect to the target site.

#### Apache Port Configuration

We also need to tell Apache to listen on our new port!

```
$ sudo echo "Listen 12345" >> /etc/apache2/ports.conf
```

This will add the line `Listen 12345` at the end of `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`. Alternatively, you could add it yourself using a text editor.

Now let's enable the site

```
$ sudo a2ensite thews_site
$ sudo invoke-rc.d apache2 restart
```

This will set our previously defined site to be *enabled*. The second command will restart Apache.

#### Testing

If you enter `http://localhost:12345` into your browser now, you should be redirected to `superuser.com`!

### Port Forwarding

Now you can set up the **port forwarding**. You would do that on your router. Tell your router to forward your public port `33333` to your local port `12345`.

Now if someone would surf to `your-public-ip:33333` **they** get redirected to `superuser.com`.

These examples were all for Debian based environments. Hopefully you'll be able to adapt them if you need to.

Good luck :)